# Add empty elements to a list

Tags: python

```
phrase = "TEST PHRASE"
progress = []

for letter in phrase:
    if letter != None:
        progress.append("-")
    else:
        progress.append("")

print progress
```

So I want this to give me ["-","-","-","-","","-","-","-","-","-"]
So that I can string.join them and get ---- -----
Basically a hidden string. 
But ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
is what I'm getting. No empty element to mark the space.

Comment: Test letter against `' '`, not `None`

Comment: Also, your indentation is off, which matters in python. Should outputting progress be inside the loop? In your else clause you append am empty string, which when joined and printed will not output anything. This seems to be what you want (hidden string),  but doesn't match the sample desired output you give: `---- -----`

Comment: @sirlark Mistake in carrying it over to this forum. I took it out of a function in my code.

Answer (score 1):

By what I understood this is what you want ?

```
phrase = "TEST PHRASE"
progress = []
for letter in phrase:
    if letter != " ":
        progress.append("-")
    else:
        progress.append("")
print progress
print " ".join(progress)   ## make sure you give a space between the quotes.
```

Output

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', '', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'] ## empty element in progress
- - - -  - - - - - -         ## empty element in join
```

Comment: This is giving me the desired list but when I do string.join, I'm getting -------A-- as before (no spaces). is that just the nature of the string.join command?

Comment: @aero26 Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @aero26 No. I have changed my code. Please look at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `!= ' '` and `append(" ")`

```
phrase = "TEST PHRASE"
progress = []

for letter in phrase:
     if letter != ' ':
        progress.append("-")
     else:
        progress.append(" ")

print ''.join( progress )
#---- ------
```

Comment: If I were to return this rather than print it, would this be a string?

Comment: @aero26 Yes, it would. assuming, `return ''.join( progress )`

Answer (score 0):

use `if letter != " ":` instead of `if letter != None`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing letter to `None` is not what you want. A space character isn't `None`. I would compare it to a space.

```
if letter != ' ':
```

Answer (score 0):

How about change your condition like this.

```
  phrase = "TEST PHRASE"
    progress = []
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter == " ":
            progress.append("")
        else:
            progress.append("-")
    print(progress)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have got what you wanted from the other answers, if all you need is to mask all the character except "white spaces", you can get less verbose using regex, like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\s]', '-', "TEST PHRASE")
'---- ------'
```